# How can i download a file from ajax call and force the results do be downloaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, download, asp.net-ajax

I have post the similar question yesterday and i haven't get the results. I have loaded data on my kendo grid and when i 
click download, i want to download the file but it is not returning results. The folder that i am downloading from is on the server not on project solution.
I created a controller to test the download without a button click and it works but i want to download from kendo button click. No error on console

**Function for getting the selected Id from the grid**

```
 function showDetails(e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

               DownloadIndexController(dataItem.possID);
               }
```

**Ajax call to the controller**

```
function DownloadIndexController(possID) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("DownloadIndex", "Poss")',
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { possID: possID },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        window.location = '@Url.Action("DownloadIndex", "Poss")';
                    }
                })
            }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult DownloadIndex(int possID)
    {
        string Filelocation = "myserverlocation"
        FileContentResult ff = null;
        try
        {
            OnePossModel md = new Models.OnePossModel();
            JsonParamBuilder myBuilder = new JsonParamBuilder();
            myBuilder.AddParam<Guid>("submittingUserID", System.Guid.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId()));
            myBuilder.AddParam<int>("possID", Convert.ToInt32(possID));

            string jsonReq = Models.JsonWrapper.JsonPOST(ApiBaseUrl + ApiPOSSSubBaseUrl + "/WritePOSSFile", myBuilder.GetJSonParam());
            string possFilename = Models.DeserialiseFromJson<string>.DeserialiseApiResponse(jsonReq);

            possFilename = possFilename.Replace(",", ",");

            string x = Filelocation + possFilename.ToString();

            var type = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet;

            byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(x);
            string myfileName = possFilename;
            ff =  File(fileBytes, type,myfileName);
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + myfileName);
            Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
            return ff;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you *return* the FileResult generated by `File()` ?

Comment: you mean i must remove Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, just add this:

```
public FileResult DownloadIndex(int possID)
{
    . . . .
    return File(fileBytes, type,myfileName);
}
```

Comment: I have made your changes and am still not getting results. even on console there's no error. i doesn't return anything

Comment: Debug your method and make sure you have not empty bytearray

Comment: I have debug and it is not returning null. byte [] got data.

Comment: Check popup blocker?

Comment: I have checked my popup. the setting is disabled

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done the way you are trying to. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax) for a workaround to simulate "ajax file download".

In your code you are making 2 requests, the first creates the file and stream it in the response (and cant be downloaded with ajax), and then the second request by setting the window.location - But the file is not "alive" any more since it was allocated to the first response.

If using the `FileResult` Action then give away the ajax call (depends on your requirements) and just use a plain link: `/poss/downloadindex/123`

Comment: @Isasac I don't really understand what you saying. can you just modify the code so that i can understand on what you are saying. thanks